# "Place the pot somewhere where it is 20–22 degrees warm."

Tags: pronouns

> Place the pot somewhere where it is 20–22 degrees warm.

The double *where* sounds a bit silly. Is there a better way to word this sentence? "Someplace 20-22 degrees warm" sounds too informal.

Comment: To have a more correct answer, you should provide the context in which you want to use the sentence. Also, as you say 20-22 degrees warm, I presume you are not measuring the temperature in Fahrenheit; I would not say it is warm when the temperature is lower than the water freezing point.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: No, it's in Kelvin.

Comment: @Tim: That means the temperature is −420.07 °F, close to the absolute zero; I still would not say it is warm. **:-)**

Comment: Don't see what's terribly wrong with the double "where". This kind of duplication will happen from time to time-- it's just a natural feature of the language (and of languages generally).

Comment: @Neil: Thanks. It felt a little silly, but I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: @Tim: Did you mean to say "20-22 degrees *warmer*"?

Comment: @Jimi: No. Is there a problem with "20-22 degrees warm"?

Comment: Jeez!  When you get the temperature issue worked out, you can replace that phrase with "Place the pot somewhere *that* is 20-22 degrees warm." :-)

Comment: @kiamlaluno Must be Celsius.

Comment: @SȱɳɨȼƮħeǶḝÐɠḝħȱɠ Probably it is, even if I would not call that warm, if not when the external temperature is 5 °C.

Comment: Tim N, there is nothing wrong with using *somewhere* in your example. Saying "someplace" instead of somewhere, sounds weird and unnatural.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Place the pot where the cat can't
>   reach it.

This would be the simplest, default construction. It will do in many cases. The point is that *somewhere* as the antecedent of *where* is superfluous, because, if you use *where* without an antecedent, something like *somewhere* is already implicit in it.

Answer (score 2):

> Place the pot somewhere that is 20-22
>   degrees warm.

Comment: Thanks. What if the subject isn't "it"? "Place the pot somewhere where the cat can't reach it."

Comment: How about "Place the pot somewhere that can't be reached by the cat"?

Comment: how about "Place the pot somewhere the cat can't reach it"...

Comment: michael, that's a good answer. The best one that I have seen, on this page.

Answer (score 1):

The smallest change would be to replace "somewhere" with "someplace".

> Place the pot someplace where it is 20-22 degrees warm.

<sub>Note that both this and the original sound a bit... awkward to my ear. I wouldn't say "X degrees warm", for example.</sub>

> Place the pot someplace warm (20 – 22 degrees).

Comment: *Someplace* is N.American informal (consulted Chambers, ODO, Collins dictionaries) and is not commonly used in BrEng, where *somewhere* is the normal expression,

Comment: That's a good point, Trevor. Saying "someplace" instead of somewhere, does sound weird and uncommon in England and the rest of the UK.

Answer (score 1):

> Place the pot at a(ny) location where it is 20–22 degrees Celsius.

Or, to go to an extreme and sound really formal:

> Ensure that the device used for containing items is located at a site which has a temperature between 20 degrees and 22 degrees Celsius, and should it fail to be at such a location, proceed to correct it until it is at a location at the desired temperature.

Answer (score 1):

As reported in the other answers, *somewhere* and *where* are superfluous; it's enough to say *where*.

> Place the pot where the temperature is 20-22 degrees.
>   Place the pot where the cat cannot reach it.

Answer (score 1):

> Place the pot in an ambient temperature of 20 to 22 degrees Celsius.

After looking at some other comments I noticed you were ambiguous regarding what measurement of temperature you had used. I have assumed Celsius because, as the other commentators say, Fahrenheit would be below freezing point.

Notice how using ambient temperature **doesn't** need the place or location mentioning.